# How to disable responses to PING

Tags: networking, security, fedora, ping

I feel like this should be a really simple thing to do, but googling and checking SF I didn't see anything.  I'm trying to make my Fedora server not respond to pings, how do I do that?

Comment: [This article](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Security/disable_ping.htm) explains how to do this.

Comment: Additionally, you can use "Blackhole" security: the server simply won't answer connection attemps to closed ports, so portscan becomes a difficult one ;)

Comment: I've never understood the advantages of disabling ICMP Echo Requests on servers. It makes monitoring and debugging network connectivity troublesome. Servers will usually have one or more low ports open for service anyway, so it's not like you can blackhole them. Could you let me know your reason, please?

Comment: It's done only for a false sense of security.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To disable the PING response, add the following line to your init script for the network:

```
echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
```

To reenable the PING response do this:

```
echo 0 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
```

---

Update:

To make the change permanent add the following line to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1
```

Comment: how can i do it for windows server family??

Answer (score 12):

It is better to use firewall for these purposes, so that you can optionally enable ping from some systems, esp monitoring systems

```
iptables -t filter -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -s monitoring_system -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP
```

Comment: Just in case it's not obvious to iptables newbies, replace "monitoring_system" with the IP/range of the server(s) which should be able to ping the server. All other ping requests will be silenty dropped.

Answer (score 11):

Add the following line to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1
```

It has the same effect as the above echo lines.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this command to disable ping request

```
sysctl net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1
```

To enable it again

```
sysctl net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=0
```

Finally save it `sysctl -p`

Comment: Weird, the opposite works on my system with Ubuntu 14.04. I am pinging localhost if it matters.

Comment: Sorry! I recheked now and corrected. Tried in CentOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
```

Answer (score 0):

open your /etc/sysctl.conf and append this line

net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 1

and execute this command

sysctl -p

it's still usable after reboot

Answer (score -1):

Firewall block ICMP connections.

especially icmp echo.

Comment: However, do not block all ICMP traffic because this will e.g. break Path MTU discovery.